# How to manage role based access control in Google App Engine Endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an application using android, objectify and google cloud datastore in which a teacher can see the records of students of the class he teach, teacher can delete a record of a student he teach, teacher can add a student in his class etc. similarly any student can see all the teachers who teach him etc.
I want assign role for teachers and students so that one teacher can not be able to access the records of other teacher and one student can not be able to access the records of other students.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google's **Directory API** to create a hierarchical structure for your users.
More info on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-org-units